# Escape double quotes from a string - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.5

"2.5 How to escape double quotes from the string.

```
select replace('"2.5','"','')
```

is working for me . But Using 'E'(escape) how i can select the data .

Comment: please sampes. like you run `select E'"2.5';` and I see `"2.5` and you don't like it?.. what the question - please explain like to a child?

Comment: @vao : Some card payment details is inserted to my log tables like "2627.56, "544.17 etc. i need to fetch the column data with out double quotes.

Comment: the what's wrong with `replace`?..